# Force bold with IHTMLDocument

Tags: mshtml, ihtmldocument

I am using an HTML editing control build on MS HTML.

I need to be able to force text to be bold/unbold and cannot find an easy way to do this.

I can toggle bold status as follows:

```
(D as IHTMLDocument2).execCommand('Bold', False, EmptyParam);
```

I can get bold status as follows:

```
bIsBold := (D as IHTMLDocument2).queryCommandValue('Bold');
```

Now of course you will say, well duh, just get the bold status and then toggle it if you need to.

Unfortunately the selected text can actually have three states: not bold/partially bolded/all bold, so i am forced to blindly toggle the status before querying it to ensure it is only in the two know states: not bold/all bold.  This is quite ugly so i would like to know if i am missing something obvious.

Thanks IA

Comment: Could you not query whether the first character is or is not bold? And toggle the entire text accordingly? In case of zero length noop.

Comment: Sorry Joop, I'm not following.  Querying the first character would still only give me to two states, "not bold" or "all bold".  I would still be unaware if it was in the "partially bold" state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but pressing the bold switch would then function expectedly (if one knows). Like in other editors.

Comment: Yes, I am satisfied with the way my Bold button works, but what i want to do is copy style from one location to another (i.e. format painting).  This requires having a reliable method for emboldening an item (as well as underlining, italicizing, etc).

Comment: Okay, I know no solution for that.